# Ubuntu 20.04 using full CPU usage

Tags: 20.04, cpu-load, gnome-settings-daemon

I have strange issue from last one day my ubuntu server machine using 100% of CPU resource, htop shows service gsd (gnome service daemon) is using full CPU.
Please confirm which service it is and how to stop or allocate few resources to it.

[htop result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Y47.jpg)

Comment: try type "sudo systemctl restart gsd.service"

Comment: Failed to restart gsd.service: Unit gsd.service not found.